# Unicode при записи в файл

Tags: windows, unicode, консоль, visual-studio, c++

Мне нужно создать консольное приложение, которое

- Считывало бы введённые пользователем символы: как англоязычные, так и русскоязычные.
- Выводила бы эти символы на экран в консоль.
- Записывала бы эти символы в файл.

С первым и вторым пунктом, как убрать кракозябры, я разобрался следующим образом:

- Подключил #include <locale>
- Весь вывод стал пропускать через функцию ToRus т.е. cout<< ToRus(L"Почему всё так сложно!")

Вот сама функция:

```
char *ToRus(wchar_t *str) {   
static char s[1024];   
CharToOem(LPCWSTR(str), s);    
return s; }
```

Но осталась проблема 3-м пунктом - с выводом в файл. В файл по-прежнему выводятся кракозябры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему, как сделать так, чтобы в файл нормально выводилась? Может вообще, как-то по-другому нужно было делать?

Comment: А как вы выводите в файл?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    wofstream f;
    f.open("C:\\DATA\\ert.txt", ios::out); // не забывайте удваивать слеш
    f << L"алла"; // обратите внимание на L, это wchar_t*, а не char*
    f.close();

То есть, Unicode-файл, а не обычный.

А ввод с клавиатуры преобразовывать в Unicode при помощи `OemToChar`.

Comment: Так я сейчас уже поправился
 f<<"алла" работает нормально.
А, код:
f << L"алла", выводит, что то странное, по моему 16 коды, аналогично и с OemToChar.
Ну а мне нужно как то вывести пользовательский ввод и когда, я его в string зпихиваю и вывожу, то в файле появляются кракозябры, а когда пытаюсь использовать OemToChar, то тоже не чего не выходит - пишется, что-то похожее на 16 ричный код.

Comment: Не-не-не, не работает нормально.

Текст в файле _должен_ быть в Unicode, так по всякому правильно.

Текст вашей программы, судя по всему, в CP1251. Консоль, в свою очередь, работает в CP866 по историческим причинам. Поэтому строка "алла" выводится в файл в CP1251, а строка, введённая пользователем, — в CP866. Чтобы победить этот зоопарк кодировок, лучше всё писать в Unicode.

---
У вас заканчивается лимит комментариев, удаляйте верхние комментарии.

Comment: Я открываю в блокноте, а там действительно по умолчанию ANSI.Я пересохранил файл в формате Unicode, но после открытия заново увидел те же коды - 008367B8, вместо слова "алла", при использовании f<<L"алла".

Comment: О, извините, я похоже ошибся, не заметил, что вместо ofstream нужно использовать wofstream. Но проблема из-за этого не исчезла. Теперь в блокнот вообще ни чего не записывается.Т.е. тут похоже дело даже не в кодировке, когда записываю в wofstream f; f << L"алла";, то он тупо ощищает указанный файл и ничего туда не пишет вообще.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Хм, не может вообще ничего не записываться. Вы не забыли закрыть файл? Посмотрите на размер файла после записи. И этот файл, понятно, надо просматривать как текст Unicode.

Comment: Не забыл вот код:
wofstream f;


 f.open("C:\\DATA\\ert234.txt", ios::out);
 f<<L"dfsdaaццццццxx";
 f.close();
Вообще, как я посмотрел, он записывает не ничего, а он записывает до первого русского символа, т.е. в этом примере в файл будет записано: dfsdaa. А если бы строка начиналась с русского символа, то ничего записано не было бы и размер файлы был-бы 0

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл! Вот вам статья: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4563/Upgrading-an-STL-based-application-to-use-Unicode. (Не смотрите часть с `tstream`/`TCHAR`, вам нужно просто `wstream`.) Или то же здесь: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?457106-Unicode-text-file&p=1741409#post1741409.

Проблема в том, что обыкновенный `wfstream` принимает Unicode-строки, а вот пишет их как не-Unicode. Но его можно заставить. Вот вам вкратце описание, как.

Первый шаг: создаёте «пустой» конвертер. В обычном случае `wchar_t*` конвертируется с потерями в обычные символы, но нам надо эту конвертацию отключить.

Код конвертера:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

typedef std::codecvt<wchar_t , char , mbstate_t> null_wcodecvt_base;

class null_wcodecvt : public null_wcodecvt_base
{
public:
    explicit null_wcodecvt(size_t refs = 0) : null_wcodecvt_base(refs) {}

protected:
    virtual result do_out(mbstate_t&,
                          const wchar_t* from,
                          const wchar_t* from_end,
                          const wchar_t*& from_next,
                          char* to,
                          char* to_end,
                          char*& to_next) const
    {
        size_t len = (from_end - from) * sizeof(wchar_t);
        memcpy(to, from, len);
        from_next = from_end;
        to_next = to + len;
        return ok;
    }

    virtual result do_in(mbstate_t&,
                         const char* from,
                         const char* from_end,
                         const char*& from_next,
                         wchar_t* to,
                         wchar_t* to_end,
                         wchar_t*& to_next) const
    {
        size_t len = (from_end - from);
        memcpy(to, from, len);
        from_next = from_end;
        to_next = to + (len / sizeof(wchar_t));
        return ok;
    }

    virtual result do_unshift(mbstate_t&, char* to, char*,
                              char*& to_next) const
    {
        to_next = to;
        return noconv;
    }

    virtual int do_length(mbstate_t&, const char* from,
                          const char* end, size_t max) const
    {
        return (int)((max < (size_t)(end - from)) ? max : (end - from));
    }

    virtual bool do_always_noconv() const throw()
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual int do_encoding() const throw()
    {
        return sizeof(wchar_t);
    }

    virtual int do_max_length() const throw()
    {
        return sizeof(wchar_t);
    }
};
```

Теперь, надо ещё переопределить `endl`.

```
std::wostream& wendl(std::wostream& out)
{
    out.put(L'\r');
    out.put(L'\n');
    out.flush();
    return out;
}
```

А вот и пример использования. Не забудьте про [BOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (такая штука в начале файла, может и не понадобиться, если не под Windows).

```
const wchar_t UTF_BOM = 0xfeff;

int main()
{
    // заводим файл
    std::wfstream file;

    // инстанциируем пустой конвертер
    null_wcodecvt wcodec(1);
    std::locale wloc(std::locale::classic(), &wcodec);
    // сообщаем файлу, что он должен использовать этот конвертер,
    // а не стандартный. обязательно делаем это _до_ открытия файла
    file.imbue(wloc);

    // открыли файл, обязательно как binary, чтобы никакой самодеятельности
    // от стандартной библиотеки
    file.open("data.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        // если текст русский, надо прогнать через `ToRus`
        std::cerr << "Failed to open data.txt for writing" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // записали в начало файла BOM
    file << UTF_BOM;
    // записали текст
    file << L"Я тоже не знаю, почему в C/C++ всё так сложно." << wendl;

    // закрыли файл
    file.close();

    // фсё!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно.